# DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (Oracle Database)

Tags: r, oracle

I am getting the DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (Oracle Database). I know my R version is 64 bits because I ran the functions below.  However I have both 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle ODBC Drivers installed on my Windows computer.

Is there a function that tells me whether R is using the 32 bit Oracle ODBC driver or the 64 bit Oracle ODBC driver?

Do I have to remove the DSNs with Oracle 32 bit drivers to prevent the DSN Mismatch error?

When I use Sys.info() on "machine" then I get "x86-64"
When I use Sys.getenv on"R_ARCH" then I get "/x64"

Comment: If your R is 64 bit then you must use also the 64-bit ODBC driver. How did you install 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle ODBC Drivers and client? Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: The DSN mismatch cleared itself up, but I'm not sure how or why.  However, now I get the database connection error below.  I've tried using database schema name and without database schema name and still get the error below.  Can someone explainthis error?  "42S02 208 Microsoft, ODBC SQL Server Driver, SQL Server, Invalid object name 'ltdb.dbo.apcTable'."